# CSS applying from console but not applying when applying from internal stylesheet with the same class

Tags: html, css, overflow

I'm trying to override overflow for a div from hidden to visible. It's a large project and I'm trying to add some new things in this.

**I'm able to apply css to the element using Inspect element console but the same thing doesn't work when adding to the file as internal stylesheet**

Tried using !*important* as well

Please let me know what might be causing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its difficult to help without seeing the code. Nevertheless, if you have updated the stylesheet with required class, try loading your page again with CTRL+F5 combination which will force the browser to reload CSS file and other files. Another option is to clear the browser cache and reload the page

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason for CSS not to work while using an internal stylesheet.

Here are two things to try, check if your class name is spelt correctly and you're using the correct selectors.

And you might have a fixed width or height which is causing the content not to be able to scroll over.

Post the code on here for more help if you can.
Mark as answer if this was helpful.